# How to use Timer inside of constructor?

Tags: c#, timer

I have a public method inside of my class that takes `DataCredentials` as a parameter and I need to trigger that method every minute

```
public Data GetData(DataCredentials dataCredentials) {...}
```

I know that I can use `Timer` for the current problem:

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    private Timer _dataUpdateTimer;
    private readonly TimeSpan _updateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

    public DataService()
    {
        _dataUpdateTimer = new Timer(GetData(?),
                                     null,
                                     TimeSpan.Zero,
                                     _updateInterval);
    }

    public Data GetData(DataCredentials dataCredentials) {...}
}
```

But how do I know about `DataCredentials`?

Before that I call this method inside of other class like this:

```
public Data GetCached(DataCredentials dataCredentials)
{
    return _dataService.GetData(dataCredentials);
}
```

Comment: If you need something else to pass in data credentials every minute, then the call from the timer needs to happen outside of your class.  If you can use the same data credentials every time, perhaps you should pass it in as a parameter to the constructor?

Comment: Well, how is `GetData` supposed to function if you don't give it `dataCredentials`. It doesn't make sense for the constructor to be able to call it if you haven't told the constructor *how* to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get the parameters needed on the `GetData(....)` as a constructor argument and hold it as a field in the class.

Then, set an elapsed callback to your timer, then start it (use `System.Timers.Timer` for that).
When elapsed, call your code, and restart the timer:

```
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    private const double UpdateInterval = 1000; //1000ms = 1s

    private readonly DataCredentials _credentials;
    private Timer _dataUpdateTimer;


    public DataService(DataCredentials credentials)
    {
        _credentials = credentials;
        _dataUpdateTimer = new Timer(UpdateInterval);

        _dataUpdateTimer.Elapsed += DataUpdateTimer_Elapsed;
        _dataUpdateTimer.Start();
    }

    private void DataUpdateTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Call your code in here
        var data = GetData(_credentials);
        //.....

        //Reset your timer
        _dataUpdateTimer.Stop();
        _dataUpdateTimer.Start();
    }

    public Data GetData(DataCredentials dataCredentials) {...}
}
```

Update: If you wonder how to use data after getting them in the interval, I suggest you implement and use the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), i.e.: registering all objects interested to those data and then notifying-dispatching all the data to them, on each interval.

Comment: But what he need to set instead of `?` inside a constructor?

Comment: Answer updated. Consider voting it as best if you think it is worth it.

Comment: So, first call of `DataUpdateTimer_Elapsed` will be with empty credentials? Where do you update it?

Comment: No, `+=` does not call it immediately, it registers it in order to be called when the time is elapsed. It is a callback function, search for this mechanism please.

Comment: You cannot pass `int` in `Timer`. `int` is not assignable to parameter `TimerCallback`

Comment: You are right, updated. Double is valid though for `System.Timers.Timer`.